# html - will meta tags make my blog heavy?

Tags: html, tags, meta

i have at lease 25 meta tags in my blog for SEO, OG, and other. Will 25 meta tags slow down my blog? I'm afraid to add more meta tags, but both are important. I'd like to add other useful meta tags but also like a blazing speed blog.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe meta tags would slow down your blog...

Comment: i'm still doubt it, are you have a proof or somewhat?

Answer (score 0):

meta tags are not as useful in seo anymore.

[Google does not use keywords meta tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.sg/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)

Comment: Thanks Jason. Yes. I know. But there still other meta tags i need like Twitter Cards.